# Application crashes, pointer to function is suspect

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

I have the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
class systemfunctions
{
    public:
    void (*sleep) (DWORD ms);

    systemfunctions ()
    {
        sleep = reinterpret_cast<void>(Sleep);
    }
} sys;
```

When I call `sys.sleep()`, the application crashes. Why does the program crash, and what can I do to resolve the problem?

Comment: Have you checked what the value of sys.sleep is when you call it?

Comment: This code won't even compile, you can't `reinterpret_cast` to `void`. Please post real code.

Comment: @GManNickG, I missed out `public:`, added that. That code does compile with MSVC's `cl` but crashes.

Comment: @user2064000: That's an enormous bug in MSVC...I wonder what it even generates. I can tell you that cast is wrong though, so should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows.h declares Sleep() like `WINBASEAPI VOID WINAPI Sleep(__in DWORD dwMilliseconds);`, try telling the compiler it needs to use the proper calling convention when it uses that pointer:

```
typedef VOID (WINAPI * SleepFunction)(DWORD ms);
SleepFunction sleep;

sleep = Sleep;
```

Comment: Get rid of the cast, too.

Answer (score 1):

The only time you should cast a function pointer is when using the return value from `GetProcAddress`.

Get rid of the cast, and then the compiler will tell you what is wrong.